# The buttons didn't respond on click when I run the program

Tags: java, butterknife

I am building up a mini-calculator via Android Studio, and finally finished. In this program, I use ButterKnife to `@bind` those views more convenient. The problem started when I run the calculator, which I couldn't receive any responds from those button when I clicked on them. I tried as many ways as possible but it didn't work. I checked my ButterKnife and it has synced already.

Here is my code:

```
package com.huy9515gmail.mycalculator;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
@BindView(R.id.btn0)
Button btn0;
@BindView(R.id.btn1)
Button btn1;
@BindView(R.id.btn2)
Button btn2;
@BindView(R.id.btn3)
Button btn3;
@BindView(R.id.btn4)
Button btn4;
@BindView(R.id.btn5)
Button btn5;
@BindView(R.id.btn6)
Button btn6;
@BindView(R.id.btn7)
Button btn7;
@BindView(R.id.btn8)
Button btn8;
@BindView(R.id.btn9)
Button btn9;

@BindView(R.id.btnPlus)
Button btnPlus;
@BindView(R.id.btnMinus)
Button btnMinus;
@BindView(R.id.btnDup)
Button btnDup;
@BindView(R.id.btnDiv)
Button btnDiv;

@BindView(R.id.btnDot)
Button btnDot;
@BindView(R.id.btnAC)
Button btnAC;
@BindView(R.id.btnC)
Button btnC;
@BindView(R.id.btnEqual)
Button btnEqual;

@BindView(R.id.edt_input)
EditText edtInput;
@BindView(R.id.txt_Answer)
TextView txtAnswer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);}

public void setEventClickViews() {
    btn0.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn3.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn4.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn5.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn6.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn7.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn8.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn9.setOnClickListener(this);

    btnPlus.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnMinus.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnDup.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnDiv.setOnClickListener(this);

    btnAC.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnC.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnDot.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnEqual.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn0:
            edtInput.append("0");
            break;
        case R.id.btn1:
            edtInput.append("1");
            break;
        case R.id.btn2:
            edtInput.append("2");
            break;
        case R.id.btn3:
            edtInput.append("3");
            break;
        case R.id.btn4:
            edtInput.append("4");
            break;
        case R.id.btn5:
            edtInput.append("5");
            break;
        case R.id.btn6:
            edtInput.append("6");
            break;
        case R.id.btn7:
            edtInput.append("7");
            break;
        case R.id.btn8:
            edtInput.append("8");
            break;
        case R.id.btn9:
            edtInput.append("9");
            break;
        case R.id.btnPlus:
            edtInput.append("+");
            break;
        case R.id.btnMinus:
            edtInput.append("-");
            break;
        case R.id.btnDup:
            edtInput.append("x");
            break;
        case R.id.btnDiv:
            edtInput.append(":");
            break;
        case R.id.btnAC:
            edtInput.setText("");
            txtAnswer.setText("");
            break;
        case R.id.btnC:
            edtInput.setText(pressC(edtInput.getText().toString()));
            break;
        case R.id.btnDot:
            edtInput.append(".");
            break;
        case R.id.btnEqual:
            pressEqual();
            break;
        default: break;
    }
}

public String pressC(String s) {
    StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder(s);
    build.deleteCharAt(build.length() - 1);
    return build.toString();
}

public void pressEqual() {
    boolean isDecimal = false;
    String s = edtInput.getText().toString();

    for (int i = 0; i <= s.length(); i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) == '.') isDecimal = true;
    }

    if (isDecimal) txtAnswer.setText(hasDecimalOperator(s));
    else txtAnswer.setText(noDecimalOperator(s));
}

public String hasDecimalOperator(String s) {
    float const1, const2, result = 0.0f;
    String s1 = new String("");
    String s2 = new String("");
    int i = 0, target;

    while ((s.charAt(i) != '+') || (s.charAt(i) != '-') || (s.charAt(i) != 'x') || (s.charAt(i) != ':')) {
        s1 += s.charAt(i);
        i++;
    }
    const1 = Float.parseFloat(s1);

    target = i;
    i++;

    while (i <= s.length()) {
        s2 += s.charAt(i);
        i++;
    }
    const2 = Float.parseFloat(s2);

    switch (s.charAt(target)) {
        case '+':
            result = const1 + const2;
        case '-':
            result = const1 - const2;
        case 'x':
            result = const1 * const2;
        case ':':
            result = const1 / const2;
    }

    return Float.toString(result);
}

public String noDecimalOperator(String s) {
    int const1, const2;
    long result = 0;
    String s1 = new String("");
    String s2 = new String("");
    int i = 0, target;

    while ((s.charAt(i) != '+') || (s.charAt(i) != '-') || (s.charAt(i) != 'x') || (s.charAt(i) != ':')) {
        s1 += s.charAt(i);
        i++;
    }
    const1 = Integer.parseInt(s1);

    target = i;
    i++;

    while (i <= s.length()) {
        s2 += s.charAt(i);
        i++;
    }
    const2 = Integer.parseInt(s2);

    switch (s.charAt(target)) {
        case '+':
            result = const1 + const2;
        case '-':
            result = const1 - const2;
        case 'x':
            result = const1 * const2;
        case ':':
            result = const1 / const2;
    }

    return Long.toString(result);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to call your `setEventClickViews ()` method in the `onCreate` method.

Comment: Omg :)))) What a ridiculous mistake :v
Anyway, thanks for you help <3